# Simple verilog to control MD1715 ultrasound driver

Tags: verilog, hardware, fpga, hdl

I'm attempting to control an TC8020 mosfet (http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/tc8020.pdf) through a md1715 ultrasound driver (http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/md1715.pdf) to eventually control ultrasound sensors.

i.e. FPGA --> MD1715 --> TC8020 --> Transmitters

From what I can tell in the md1715 truth tables (md1715.pdf page 4), I should be able to drive an output voltage by something like SEL=1, POS=1, NEG=0?

I'm trying to do something like this in my verilog code, but it's been a long time since I've used a HDL. Does something like this make sense? I'm not exactly sure how to change frequencies, etc.

```
module main(input ADC0CLK, 
                output SELA, //pin mappings set up to fpga
                output POSA,
                output NEGA
    );

reg r_sel_a;
reg r_pos_a;
reg r_neg_a;

/*
// Hardwire for now just to test output. 
// From what I can tell this should drive a constant voltage of 1?
assign SELA = 1'b1;
assign POSA = 1'b1;
assign NEGA = 0;
*/

assign SELA = r_sel_a;
assign POSA = r_pos_a;
assign NEGA = r_neg_a;

always @ (posedge ADC0CLK or negedge ADC0CLK)
begin: TRANSMITA
    if (ADC0CLK == 1) begin
        r_sel_a <= 1'b1;
        r_pos_a <= 1'b1;
        r_neg_a <= 0;
    end else if (ADC0CLK == 0) begin
        r_sel_a <= 1'b1;
        r_pos_a <= 0;
        r_neg_a <= 1'b1;
    end
end

endmodule
```

Much thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is not synthezisable. You cannot have a process (always) that works on both edges of clock. I see two options here:

1. You can use 2x faster clock and then your process will work only on posedge of this faster clock.
2. You can use ODDR primitve. ODDR is a xilinx primitive to drive data on two clock edges, [here](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug471_7Series_SelectIO.pdf) you can find description of xilinx 7-series IO resources. if you are using FPGA from other vendors then you have to search for such primitive, I found that altera has ALTDDIO_OUT ipcore but I've never used it.

Imo option 2 is better, you shouldn't have timing problems which can occure in first option.

Comment: Thanks, right that makes sense. If I wanted to test that this actually works and gives me a voltage though, I should just be able to uncomment the block of coe and remove the always block for now, right? I.e. without any valid clock signal?

Comment: Well I've never try such a simple design without any clocks but it should work.